# FileOutputStream NPE when deployed in glassfish

Tags: spring-boot, glassfish-5

As the title says, the program is working fine when deployed in tomcat. However, when deployed in glassfish which is our production server, it throws null pointer exception in this line.

```
@Autowired
ServletContext context;

FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(new File(context.getRealPath("resources/"+filename)));
```

Comment: You cannot write to files inside the classpath. It might work if the container unpacks the war, but changes won't persist (after redeploy everything will be gone). So in short don't write, from your code, to files inside your classpath.

Comment: I am generating an excel file using apache poi and want to send it to the client for download. Can you suggest other options on how to do this?

Comment: Don't generate that file inside your archive... Generate it in the temp directory instead.

Comment: Is archive my war file? I'm creating a temp directory somewhere in the local server and get it from there is that what you mean? sorry I'm not good in english.

Comment: The archive is your `WAR` file, you cannot (and shouldn't) write to it. Just use the `temp` dir, by using `File.createTemporaryFile` or use the `java.io.tmpdir` system property to retrieve it.

Comment: I've tried the createTempFile method but how do I write to the temp file? It only creates a blank excel file. And the write method from the poi requires an outputstream

Comment: Just replace `new File(...)` with `File.createTempFile(filename, null)` nothing more nothing less.